# Show f is continuous

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x^2+y^2} & \text{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
0 & \text{if } (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}
$$
Show that f is a continuous function

Comment: It's not continuous.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought but the question in my homework specifically says show that f is a continuous function so I don't know what to do?

Comment: I contacted my lecturer and she said there was a typo in the question so I have edited the function to show what it was meant to be. Is this new function continuous?

Comment: No, it's still not continuous at $(0,0)$. You can see for yourself that it is unbounded in any neighbourhood of the origin, just like the previous function.

Answer (score 0):

By using two path test, when $x=0$ and $y=0$ $\lim f(x,y)$ get different value.
So it should be discontinuous at the origin.

Comment: Perhaps you meant that taking $\;y=0\;$ we get $\;\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1x\;$, which doesn't exist, and something very similar if we take $\;x=0\;$ ? Of course, it is enough with one of these cases.

Comment: Ya this is what i meant.